# Restore database backup avoiding replication

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, database-replication, database-backups

I'm trying to restore a database backup. The original database has replication settings.

When I do the restore using the following:

```
exec('RESTORE DATABASE [mydatabase] FROM  DISK = ''' + @filename + ''',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10')
```

It throws an error

```
Database was restored, however an error was encountered while replication was being restored/removed. The database has been left offline. See the topic MSSQL_ENG003165 in SQL Server Books Online.

RESTORE could not start database

RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

What's worst. My actual replication on my other 3 servers went offline after this...

So what I want to achieve is my database to be restored but WITHOUT any replication at all. Just the database tables, stored procedures, etc.

The database I'm trying to restore is from a PUBLISHER.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for that topic on Books Online?

Comment: I want to be sure the replication won't affect my production servers again. Didn't expect the restore to my DEV machine would affect the actual replication on the production servers.

Comment: I tried to say that in the last line of my original question "What's worst. My actual replication on my other 3 servers went offline after this..."  I have 3 production servers where one is a publisher and 2 subscribers and another subscriber in a remote location. I'm trying to have a dev machine with a copy of this database restored automatically every week. But I'm facing this issue I described...